# What are some alternatives to List view for large list (over 100k items)?

Tags: list, document-library, list-view

what are some other alternatives to present data to user beside list view (since there is threshold of 5k setup by sp admin)? I have few lists and libraries that contains items over 50k to 100k.

I am open to suggestion including design change. We have tool that can move data between old list to new list if I have redesign some of these lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has some very [clear and relatively simple guidelines](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-HA010173667.aspx) for dealing with the List View Threshold.  In that, I have found that the first three tips in that document (Indexed Columns, Filtered Views and Folders) solve 95% of the cases where this comes up.  The remaining 5% generally have unusual business requirements and need a custom solution.

5,000 items is well beyond the limits of what a human can reasonably process so I'm assuming that you need this for some other purpose, such as exports, archives or complex reporting.  For that, you might need to export your lists to Access as it batches requests and is not subject to the List View Threshold, though Access can only process lists, not libraries.

Answer (score 0):

First of, well done for not increasing the throttle limit right away; as many have.

I think Dave's link covers everything really.  One little tip that I'd like to pass on is changing the default view on any of these parent lists to show items from an acceptable time period.  For me, it was 6 months.

Anything else can then be seperated out into views with filtered columns and folders as needed.

I'd aslo suggest checking whether your migration tool preserves the original Time / Author stamps too before deciding whether these need to be moved.